# EF4 Code only ctp5: how set connectionstring devart oracle?

Tags: code-first, entity-framework-ctp5, ef4-code-only, devart

hi i have devart oracle provider 6(BETA), and want use code only ctp5...how i can set connectionstring for oracle?i started now with Code only and i need use oracle, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find example and tutorial about Code-First usage by the following link - http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/index.php/entity-framework-code-first-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite.html

Answer (score 1):

OracleConnection you have to add refference: Devart.Oracle.Data i think.

it's very simple, if you do have any questions i use it too and i write code only applications.

Answer (score 1):

OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConnection"].ConnectionString)

I am doing it like so.

using Devart.Data.Oracle;